# How to auto_now_add to django DateTimeField only if field was not used as objects.create() parameter?

Tags: django

I have DateTimeField:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to use auto_now_add option only if entry was created with admin or with constructor like this:

```
instance = MyModel.objects.create(no_created_at_there)
```

Otherwise I want to use value used in constructor. How to realise that?

Comment: That is the default behaviour.

Comment: There's another way instead of `auto_now_add` although `auto_now_add` should also work as you have described. Instead, use `default` parameter: `created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)`

Comment: It's seem to me, that you confused to options: auto_now_add & auto_now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was resolved by Shang Wang's suggestion from question's comment.
I've just replaced `auto_now_add` parameter with `default=datetime.now`